# using selenium to search a search bar on forums - automatically opens google chrome page of website each time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, discord.py

```
def getUserPage(user):  

    d = webdriver.Chrome()
    d.get(url here)
    e = d.find_element_by_name('username')
    e.send_keys(user)
    e.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    return d.current_url
```

(in  a discord.py bot)
that's my code to get the given user's profile page URL and I have another function which webscrapes that URL to give some information. but whenever I or any other user runs the command $profile username it opens up the google chrome page with the website then does the web scraping and shows the information in discord. is there a way to disable it automatically opening a google chrome page of the website for me and anyone else using the bot?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that before.
If you do it on localhost (aka your own computer) it will pop up.
However, if you use a host ,for example Replit, it will not open up.